# How can I insert Controller Name inside a actionlink without adding other stuffs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, actionlink

This is my actionlink:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", new { id = item.NewsId, title = item.Title + "#disqus_thread"}).ToString()))
```

I would like to add Controller Name to it but when I try that I need to add a routevalue before.. I dont want do that.

Any kind of solutions or help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this overload?

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

ActionLink Code:-

```
Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Comment", "MyController",new { id = item.NewsId, title = item.Title + "#disqus_thread"},null)
```

Comment: Where do I add that overload?

Comment: No need to add it it  it is just doc snippet.

Comment: Now the href is /home/comment/ and nothing else :S its suppose to be /home/comment/13123/text-of-item#disqus_thread

Comment: Its seems that it cuts the href string after /action/ with your snippit